# Finding expected value

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, uniform-distribution

I am not sure of how to find the value asked in below question. Any help would be appreciated.

> Suppose that the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is the uniform
>   distribution on the <strike>circle</strike> disc $x^2 + y^2 < 1$. Find $E(X|Y )$

Comment: I suppose `x2` is $x^2$..?

Comment: Hint: find the pdf of $X|Y=y$

Comment: @wolfies Hint for a much easier solution: using a symmetry of the disk $x^2+y^2 \lt 1$, show that the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is the distribution of $(-X,Y)$. Because this implies $E(X|Y)=-E(X|Y)$, you are done.

Answer (score 3):

Again, in the hopes that this question doesn't remain unanswered:

As wolfies suggests, the density of $X|Y=y$ is quite simple to evaluate:

$\qquad$[image][image]

In the left hand plot, the bivariate density is represented by the shading (which is uniform). The conditional density is readily worked out.

However, as whuber indicates, the symmetry of the problem implies that the bivariate distribution of $(-X,Y)$ is the same as that of $(X,Y)$; the immediate implication that $E(X|Y)=E(-X,Y)=-E(X,Y)$ make the problem trivial.

Either approach (or indeed some other approaches) would be a suitable means to the result.

Comment: While @whuber's comment is the easiest way to the answer sought in this case, I would suggest that wolfie's approach is a better one in general. Once it is realized that the conditional density of $X$ is _uniform_ on an interval, we can jump to the conclusion that $E[X\mid Y = y]$ is the _midpoint_ of the interval without needing to calculate that the conditional pdf has value $\frac{1}{2|y|}$ on $(-|y|,|y|)$ etc. For example, this notion would give $E[X\mid Y = y] = a$ if the disc were $\{(x,y)\colon (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 < r^2\}$.